# How to syntax-highlight XML in CDATA elements in Vim?

Tags: xml, vim, syntax-highlighting

Vim's syntax highlighting for XML/XSL is great, except it turns off all syntax highlighting in CDATA regions. Is there a way to turn on syntax highlighting on in CDATA regions?

At work, we have a lot of XSL code embedded within other XML documents. It would be great if I could get all of the goodness of XML editing for the embedded XSL code as well without having to temporarily remove the CDATA tags, or copy the CDATA content into a temporary file.

Example:

```
<root>
  <with type="xsl"><![CDATA[
      <xsl:template match="/">
          <!-- XSL content here -->
      </xsl:template>
   ]]>
  </with>
</root>
```

The XSL is always contained within , so there is something to match against.

We also sometimes embed Javascript inside CDATA regions as well. It would be nice to turn on Javascript syntax highlighting for those regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible.

I've left this question open for 9 months with no progress, and my own research has found nothing useful. Thus, I have no choice but to conclude that it simply isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

The `syntax include` directive is specifically intended to accomplish this kind of thing, and `xml.vim` (in recent versions, yours may differ) has a "hook" cluster called `xmlCdataHook` that you can override with your own syntax files.

Open your `xml.vim` syntax file and add this line:

```
syn include @xmlCdataHook <sfile>
```

This gives you xml syntax highlighting inside CDATA sections. Point to another file like `<sfile>:p:h/javascript.vim` in order to get javascript highlighting.

Alternatively, you can avoid editing the `xml.vim` file and just add your own syntax hook for CDATA sections:

```
syntax include @JS $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/javascript.vim
syntax region start=/\V<![CDATA[/ end=/\V]]>/ contains=@JS
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. The XML in the CDATA section continues to be treated as plain text.  Should I be replacing <sfile> with something?

Comment: No, <sfile> refers to "this file".

Comment: Okay, any idea why I cannot get this to work? I'm using Vim 7.3 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the syntax highlighting script that comes with vim (it's in `/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/xml.vim` on my system). However, I'm pretty sure this is a bad idea - you will be operating under the 'illusion' that the content of the CDATA section is actually XML and it's definitely not - as it's in a CDATA section it's just text.

In order to handle embedded javascript (which seems less risky to me) you will also need to create a modified syntax highlighter. A good place to start looking for information on how to do this would be the [XHTML](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1236) syntax highlighter for vim - that supports embedded languages

Comment: Looks like you can augment a syntax file by placing your modifications in a `~/.vim/after/filetype.vim` file. So I could alter the syntax highlighting rules for xml by creating `~/.vim/after/xml.vim`.  I'm just not sure what to put in the file...

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten that file (I've moved from mostly vim to mostly GUI editors these days). This is probably a question you should ask on the vim mailing lists I suspect